# How can I format C# XML-documentation as PDF or static HTML?

Tags: .net, xml-documentation

There is this question: [How to format Visual Studio XML documentation for display on the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199002/how-to-format-visual-studio-xml-documentation-for-display-on-the-web/5199033), which is similar to what I want. But the answers for this question are all very old and the tools mentioned (sandcastle, docu, NDoc, AutoHelp) are all outdated and not maintained anymore since years.

Is there a modern tool that generates a PDF (or static HTML) from XML doc strings in a .NET project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Doxygen (http://www.doxygen.nl/). There's plenty options to adjust it and use multiple languages like C# / VB.NET and much more.

Comment: This does exactly what I need: Generate PDF and HTML documentation for my C# code. Thanks!

Comment: Doxygen doesn't output PDF

Comment: It does, but indirectly. It generates LaTeX output so it's possible to create a PDF. Check out the link: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/output.html