# function in visual studio to create documentation similar to javadocs?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, javadoc

Is there a easy way to create documentation pages based on xml documentation in visual studio 2010/c# like there is in ecplipse/java javadocs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Visual Studio have an option to generate html documentation for Javadoc-style comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935351/does-visual-studio-have-an-option-to-generate-html-documentation-for-javadoc-sty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You'll have to use external plugin/or application. I use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

[Sandcastle is another choice](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/). There are some others - search the SO history.

Answer (score 3):

[Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) is one such option

Comment: I was going to add Sandcastle to my answer, but you beat me to it.  Now it would just look dumb if I added it.  ;-)    +1 to you and surfen.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/). It creates javadoc style HTML documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. XML Code Commenting  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx  createds the XML comments.

There are several tools out there to turn those into nice looking pages via xslt.  A quick bing search brings up a bunch: http://www.bing.com/search?q=XML+code+comments+xslt&form=CMDTDF&pc=CMDTDF&src=IE-SearchBox